# Stop ord() from using characters other than letters - caesar cypher

Tags: python, python-3.x, caesar-cipher, ord

I'm attempting to make a very simple caesar cipher in python 3.2, and have got most of the code.

```
aEnd = ""
        aOffset = int(input("What would you like the offset of your message to be?:\n"))
        aMessage = input("What message would you like to encrypt?:\n")
        for i in range(len(aMessage)):
            eAscii=ord(aMessage[i])
            aEnd = aEnd + chr(eAscii + aOffset)     
print(aEnd)
```

However, when it gets past z, instead of going straight back to a, it continues through to symbols etc. so "xyz" with an offset of 3, instead of being "abc" it becomes "{|}". How do I change this so it only uses the alphabet?

Comment: Use the modulo operator `%` and account for the offset of alphabetic chars in ascii

Comment: Have a look at `man ascii` to limit the set of your valid characters. Also you forloop is not very pythonic, why not `for letter in aMessage`

Answer (score 1):

First, adjust the return value of `ord()` so that it represents an offset into the alphabet.  I'm converting everything to lowercase here in order to simplify the code; you could create separate cases for upper vs lowercase if you want to preserve that.

```
index = ord(aMessage[i].lower())) - ord('a')
```

This returns a zero-based index into the alphabet.  E.g., the letter `a` returns `0`, `b` returns `1`, etc.

Then use this value + your offset as an index into an array of letters:

```
import string
letters = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_lowercase
replacement = letters[index + offset]
```

By creating an array `letters` containing the alphabet -- twice -- we are able to simply add an arbitrary offset, even to letters at the end of the alphabet, and get the correct replacement value.

This obviously only works with the ASCII character set and does not preserve case, but it should be enough to get you started.